# Email not firing

Tags: email, workflow

I have workflows that will fire a few emails. Till 6 hours back, all the emails were firing perfectly. Now, only emails of selective workflows are firing. When I checked the email log, the emails that were not fired had the `Mail Event` as `P` (Permanent Failure). What is the cause for this? I have not changed my email id or the workflow rules.

Update:

```
550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's\r\n550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if\r\n550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit\r\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC\r\n550 5.7.1 initiative. k5si16461036qkh.65 - gsmtp

554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons.  See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN7253.html
```

These are 2 errors present in the Email Log

Comment: Did you check email deliverability setting in setup? It should be set to "All email"

Comment: Yup, it is "All Email"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given message:-

> Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to
>   domain's\r\n550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of
>   yahoo.com domain if\r\n550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please
>   visit\r\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to
>   learn about DMARC\r\n550 5.7.1 initiative. k5si16461036qkh.65 - gsmtp

You will not be able to send message from the domain name yahoo.com. The only solution would be is change the sender's (from) email Id to other domain like gmail etc.

Comment: Yeah but why is that? I mean why am I not able to send it from Yahoo?

Comment: Their DMARC policy doesn't allow receive email having/missing particular attributes. Its all yahoo server's configuration which is not allowing email. @User2529